# Has there been a change to the Community Bot that stops it from bumping questions?

Tags: support

Since about mid-January it seems that the 'bumps' from the Community bot have almost completely dried up. As a result, the site appears much less active than it used to be.

Is this something local, or a system-wide change?

Answer (score 2):

It took a bit of searching to find the answer, but it seems the change is real, and system-wide. The change happened [on or around January 8th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346604/why-is-the-community-user-so-determined-to-bump-this-question/378736#378736):

> OK, I've added a change here so that the community user can't rebump a question unless the original bump is more than 90 days in the past.
>
> The problem here was caused back in 2011 when the bumps were weighted a little more towards questions that had been already been viewed. The outcome all this time later was that more bumps got more views got more bumps got more views and so forth.
>
> After this build goes out in a few there should be a lot more variety to what gets bumped.

---

For the time being, we may just have to get used to the site appearing much quieter than before.